# if $d\mid n$ then $x^d-1\mid x^n-1$ proof

Tags: proof-verification, divisibility

How would you show that if $d\mid n$ then $x^d-1\mid x^n-1$ ?

My attempt :

> $dq=n$ for some $q$. $$ 1+x+\cdots+x^{d-1}\mid 1+x+\cdots+x^{n-1} \tag 1$$ in fact, $$(1+x^d+x^{2d}+\cdots+x^{(q-1)d=n-d})\cdot(1+x+\cdots+x^{d-1}) = 1+x+x^2 + \cdots + x^{n-1}$$
>
> By multiplying both sides of $(1)$ by $(x-1)$ we get that $1-x^d\mid 1-x^n$ which is the final result

Is this an ok proof?

Comment: How do you know, or from where do you get, the very first relation to the right of your $\;(1)\;$?

Comment: @DonAntonio If you divide $x^d-1$ by $x-1$ you should get the series.  Its an identity.

Comment: @CogitoErgoCogitoSum Oh, I know you *must* get that...but how? That precisely is part of the proof, as far as I see it...

Comment: See my edits for proper MathJax usage. In particular, I change $a|b$ to $a\mid b$ and used \cdots and \tag.

Comment: I'm with DonAntonio on this.  It seems the only way to get this long identities which are not at all self apperant is from actually proofing *this* result first.  Which should be simply a matte of notint $(x^{n-d} +... + 1)(x^d + 1) = x^n - 1$.

Comment: I would disagree, guys. Why dont you prove 1+1=2 while youre at it.  Its unnecessary.  I agree more could have been shown, but I disagree that this needs to be proved or even so much as cited. This is one of those properties that can be found in most any algebra book and would probably be prerequisite knowledge to this particular problem.

Answer (score 2):

An idea for you:

$$d\,\mid\,n\implies n=qd\;,\;\;q\in\Bbb Z\;,\;\;\text{and from here}: $$

$$x^n-1=\left(x^d\right)^q-1=\left(x^d-1\right)\left(\left(x^d\right)^{q-1}+\left(x^d\right)^{q-2}+\ldots+x^d+1\right)$$

The above uses the basic relation from geometric series:

$$x^a-1=(x-1)(x^{a-1}+x^{a-2}+\ldots+x+1)\;,\;\;a\in\Bbb N$$

Comment: Since the question asked about the attempt at a proof, perhaps it would be better to give a hint rather than simply display the answer.

Comment: @user43687 Perhaps...yet the OP already wrote down a good try, so giving out the basic stuff isn't bad imo. And the question did **not** ask about the attempted proof but "How would you show..." , and **then** it gives it a try.

Comment: To be honest I was just wondering if my proof is good. Thanks for the answer anyway, I think you wrote q instead of k

Answer (score 0):

Let $\alpha$ be a solution to the equation $x^d = 1$.  We then have that $\alpha^d$ = 1.  Since $d|n$ we can write $n = d\cdot k$ for some integer $k$.  Thus $$1 = 1^k = \left( \alpha^d \right)^k = \alpha^{d\cdot k} = \alpha^n$$
This shows that $\alpha$ is a solution to $x^n = 1$.

This shows that $x^d-1|x^n-1$.

Answer (score 0):

You can always do:

$f(y)=1+y+ \dots +y^{r-1}$ so that $yf(y)=y+y^2+\dots +y^r$ and $yf(y)-f(y)=(y-1)f(y)=y^r-1$

Then put $y=x^d$ with $dr=n$ and obtain $(x^d-1)f(x^d)=x^n-1$ and by construction $f(x^d)$ is a polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

Hint from Dummit and Foote:

Suppose $n= kd+r$, where $0 \leq r < d$ we have 
$$x^n -1 = x^{kd+r} - x^r + x^r -1 = x^r (x^{kd}-1) + (x^r -1)$$
then 
can you conclude $d|n$ if and only if $x^d-1 | x^n-1$.

Comment: surely that is circular and one is intended to prove *this* result first.

Answer (score 0):

Notice that for any $x$ and and natural $n$ that $$(x-1)(x^{n-1} + ..... + x + 1) = (x^n + x^{n-1} +....... +x) - (x^{n-1} + x^{n-2} +.... +1) = x^n -1$$ so that $x-1|x^n - 1$ always.

**Lemma:** $x-1|x^n-1$ for natural $n$.

Now $d|n$ so let $m = \frac nd$ and let $y= x^d$.

Then $y-1|y^m -1$.

But $y-1 = x^d -1$ and $y^m -1 = x^n - 1$.

In particular:  $(x^d -1)(x^{n-d} + x^{n-2d} + ..... + x^d + 1) = x^n - 1$

Answer (score 0):

You have:
$$d\mid n \Rightarrow n=ad$$
Then:
$$x^n-1=x^{ad}-1=(x^d)^a-1$$
Setting $x^d=y$ (just for simplifying the process) we have:
$$y^a-1=(y-1)(y^{a-1}+\dots+y+1)=(x^d-1)((x^d)^{a-1}+\dots + x^d+1)$$
In other words we showed that:
$$x^n-1=   (x^d-1)((x^d)^{a-1}+\dots + x^d+1) $$
Which obviously implies that:
$$x^d-1 \mid x^n-1$$

Comment: You missed the opening brackets at the end of lines 6 and 8. Moreover, this method is identical with that of DonAntonio.